# Проверка имен на буквы Contact Form 7

Tags: php, wordpress, регулярные-выражения, contact-form7

Пытаюсь создать фильтр на проверку поля имени на цифры. Написал подобный код:

```php
function my_wpcf7_validate_text( $result, $tag ) {
    $type = $tag['type'];
    $name = $tag['name'];
    $value = $_POST[$name] ;

    if ( strpos( $name , 'name' ) !== false ){
        $regex = '^[A-zА-яЁё]+$';
        $Valid = preg_match($regex,  $value, $matches );
        if ( $Valid > 0 ) {
        } else {
            $result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'invalid_name' ) );
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text*', 'my_wpcf7_validate_text' , 10, 2 );

add_filter( 'wpcf7_messages', 'mywpcf7_text_messages' );
function mywpcf7_text_messages( $messages ) {
    return array_merge( $messages, array(
        'invalid_name' => array(
            'description' => __( "Name is invalid", 'contact-form-7' ),
            'default' => __( 'Name seems invalid.', 'contact-form-7' )
        )
    ));
}
```

Кирилические буквы почему-то не проходят. Что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полагаю, вам поможет такое регулярное выражение `/^[a-zа-яё]+$/iu`. И сам код проверки я бы изменил:

```php
if ( !preg_match('/^[a-zа-яё]+$/iu', $value) ) {
    $result->invalidate( $tag, wpcf7_get_message( 'invalid_name' ) );
}
```

Comment: Отлично, то что нужно!